# Styling Telerik RadScheduleView (Fonts for date at the upper tab)

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, telerik, radscheduleview

How can I change font size for **Telerik RadScheduleView**'s date at the upper tab/menu (don't know how to name it)? I want to make the size of type bigger.
Can't attach an image for some reason. There is a lot information about styling appointments on **Telerik** website but nothing about styling that menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've edited `<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{telerik1:VisualStudio2013Resource ResourceKey=FontFamily}"/>` within `<Style x:Key="NavigationIntervalStyle" TargetType="ContentControl">` inside the file **Telerik.Windows.Controls.ScheduleView.xaml** to get the needed result, hope it helps someone.